# Passing uint8_t to another viewController EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uint8t

Im using AVFoundation to take a still image from the camera in the kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange format. I get all the data from the buffer and i want to pass it to another view controller.

I have a `uint8_t *yBuffer;` and i pass this pointer to the delegate method `(didCaptureImage:withYBuffer:)` of the current controller.

The other controller sets its variable `uint8_t *YBuffer` to the one received from the delegate.

The problem is that after copying the YBuffer in the new controller, and i try to modify a value in the array, it gives me the error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x104e40010)`

I tried debugging and it seems to me the YBuffer pointer in the new controller stores the YBuffer value from the delegate controller until the delegate is released from memory.

Value of YBuffer in new controller before delegate released: `"/87/34/45/76..and so on"`

Value of YBuffer in new controller after delegate released: `""` its just empty quotes.

Maybe the problem is the way i copy the `uint8_t` array? Please someone guide me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
otherController.yBuffer = malloc(inWidth * inHeight  * sizeof(uint8_t) ); //size you want to allocate

memcpy(otherController.yBuffer, yBuffer, inWidth * inHeight  * sizeof(uint8_t)); //copy to target buffer from current buffer, with the size you allocated
```

After you are done with the buffer and don't need it:

```
free(self.cameraViewController.yBuffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

A uint8_t* must point somewhere. Where does it point? Does the thing it points to go away soon?

Storing a uint8_t* in an object is highly suspicious, unless it is allocated with malloc and you have a proper setter the free()s the previous value, and a dealloc that sets the pointer to NULL via the setter.

Comment: yes the thing it points to goes away, so my pointer value gets set to nothing, its empty. What is the proper way to make a new copy of uint8_t* ?